# 403 Forbidden 453 - You currently have access to a subset of Twitter API v2 endpoints and limited v1.1 endpoints only

Tags: python, twitter, nlp, tweepy

I had recently registered for the free level Twitter API, and I would like to use Tweepy to help me extract tweets from users.

```py
api_key = config['twitter']['api_key']
api_secret = config['twitter']['api_key_secret']

access_token = config['twitter']['access_token']
access_token_secret = config['twitter']['access_token_secret']

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(api_key, api_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth)
tweets = api.home_timeline()
```

But after I ran it, the below error showed up:

> Forbidden: 403 Forbidden 453 - You currently have access to a subset
> of Twitter API v2 endpoints and limited v1.1 endpoints (e.g. media
> post, oauth) only. If you need access to this endpoint, you may need a
> different access level. You can learn more here:
> https://developer.twitter.com/en/portal/product.

If I understand correctly, the Twitter API document did allow for free-level access. However, I am not sure why it does not work for me.

Does any professional know how to solve this issue?

Comment: The "free" 2.0 API only allows you CREATE tweets.  It does not allow you to make any queries.  https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api

Comment: @TimRoberts,  I was previously able to create tweets. Now I am unable to create tweets...

Answer (score 15):

Sorry, my friend, but you cannot use the **Search Tweets** feature using the **Free Level Access** on the Twitter API.

You can use the **Manage Tweets** and **User Lookup** features on **Free Level Access**.

For the **Search Tweets** feature, you have to upgrade to the **Basic Level**.

For more information:

https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api

Comment: hello bro, I have one question, If I want to check whether user had followed another user, How I can do that with What Level access?

Comment: @NhutPham Post it as a question.

Comment: [How to fix Forbidden: 403 Forbidden 453 - You currently have access to a subset of Twitter API v2 endpoints and limited v1.1 endpoints (e.g. media post, oauth) only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76810100/how-do-i-fix-403-forbidden-error-when-using-tweepy-to-access-the-twitter-api/76810679#76810679)

Comment: @FuturistForever How can I list my own tweets?

Comment: @Volatil3 Refer [https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/client.html#tweepy.Client.get_users_tweets](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/client.html#tweepy.Client.get_users_tweets) [https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/timelines/api-reference/get-users-id-tweets](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/timelines/api-reference/get-users-id-tweets)