# How do I fix '403 Forbidden' error when using Tweepy to access the Twitter API?

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I have a Twitter developer account with free access. From my understanding, I’m able to post tweets. But I keep getting an error.

This is the code:

```py
import tweepy, sqlite3 as db, os

# Put your Twitter API keys and stuff here
CONSUMER_KEY = ""
CONSUMER_SECRET = ""
ACCESS_TOKEN = ""
ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET = ""

auth = tweepy.OAuth1UserHandler(
    CONSUMER_KEY, 
    CONSUMER_SECRET, 
    ACCESS_TOKEN, 
    ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET
)
api = tweepy.API(auth)
```

This is the error:

> tweepy.errors.Forbidden: 403 Forbidden 453 - You currently have access
> to a subset of Twitter API v2 endpoints and limited v1.1 endpoints
> (e.g. media post, oauth) only. If you need access to this endpoint,
> you may need a different access level. You can learn more here:
> https://developer.twitter.com/en/portal/product

I tried to regenerate all keys, but still no help.

Comment: Error could not be clearer `You currently have access to a subset of Twitter API v2 endpoints and limited v1.1 endpoints (e.g. media post, oauth) only. If you need access to this endpoint, you may need a different access level` your free tier acces might not include whatever endpoint you're calling.` I't snot saying that the api key is wrong but that it's not enough so regenerating the keys won't change you access level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you are trying to call the **Twitter API v1.1**, which can only be used for **Media Uploads**.

For **Tweet Creation**, you have to call the **Twitter API v2**.

Example:

```py
# Authenticate to Twitter
client = tweepy.Client(
    consumer_key=CONSUMER_KEY,
    consumer_secret=CONSUMER_SECRET,
    access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN,
    access_token_secret=ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET
)

# Post Tweet
message = " MESSAGE "
client.create_tweet(text=message)
print("Tweeted!")
```

For posting a tweet with an image:

```py
# Authenticate to Twitter
client = tweepy.Client(
    consumer_key=CONSUMER_KEY,
    consumer_secret=CONSUMER_SECRET,
    access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN,
    access_token_secret=ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET,
)
auth = tweepy.OAuth1UserHandler(
    CONSUMER_KEY,
    CONSUMER_SECRET,
    ACCESS_TOKEN,
    ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET,
)

# Create API object
api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True)

# Create tweet
message = " MESSAGE "

# Upload image
media = api.media_upload("tweet_img.png")

# Post tweet with image
client.create_tweet(text=message, media_ids=[media.media_id])
print("Tweeted!")
```

For more information:

https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api

https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/client.html#tweepy.Client.create_tweet

I hope this helps.

Comment: this is the full code: https://paste.pythondiscord.com/IHGA ..... Full error: https://snipboard.io/QbVXNl.jpg I don't know what else to do.

Comment: @BAT-FA `api.update_status_with_media()` This endpoint has been DEPRECATED and should no longer be used.

Comment: @BAT-FA Instead, you can use `client.create_tweet()`.

Comment: @BAT-FA Kindly refer to the answer.

Comment: now this error: https://snipboard.io/kA1PnC.jpg ..... code: https://paste.pythondiscord.com/53BA

Comment: @BAT-FA Before calling `client.create_tweet()`, you need to get the **media_id** by using `api.media_upload()` (If you want to post a tweet with an image). Kindly refer to the second code snippet provided in the answer.

Comment: error: https://snipboard.io/MV24B1.jpg code: https://paste.pythondiscord.com/OIRA

Comment: @BAT-FA Modify lines 81 and 82 : `media = api.media_upload(frame_path)` `client.create_tweet(text = msg, media_ids = [media.media_id])`.

Comment: lets gooooo!!!! Thank you man, wouldn't have done without you. Wish you all the best :)