# Scraping Twitter Data using tweepy or any other library

Tags: twitter, tweepy

I am trying to Scrap twitter data but not able to do so. Tried with 2-3 methods discussed over internet but all in vain. Please help me. Attaching the code and errors below:

```
import tweepy


api_key = ''
api_key_secret = ''
access_token = ''
access_token_secret = ''


client_id = ""
client_secret = ""

authenticator = tweepy.OAuthHandler(api_key, api_key_secret)
authenticator.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

api = tweepy.API(authenticator, wait_on_rate_limit=True)

crypto_coin = "bitcoin"
search_term = f'{crypto_coin} -filter:retweets'

tweet_cursor = tweepy.Cursor(api.search_tweets, q= search_term, lang="en",
tweet_mode="extended").items(10)

tweets = [tweet.full_text for tweet in tweet_cursor]
print(tweets)
```

`your text`

Comment: Error I am getting constantly is: Status Failed On, 403 Forbidden
453 - You currently have access to a subset of Twitter API v2 endpoints and limited v1.1 endpoints (e.g. media post, oauth) only. If you need access to this endpoint, you may need a different access level. You can learn more here: https://developer.twitter.com/en/portal/product

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76810679/19964724) solve your problem?

Comment: Thanks for replying, the solution you reffered is for Posting (Push request) on twitter, but i want to scrap the data from twitter, i.e PULL Request.

Answer (score 0):

To use the **Search Recent Tweets** feature, you have to call the **Twitter API v2** (**Basic Level Access** is required).

```py
# Authenticate to Twitter
client = tweepy.Client(
    consumer_key=CONSUMER_KEY,
    consumer_secret=CONSUMER_SECRET,
    access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN,
    access_token_secret=ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET
)

# Search Tweets
crypto_coin = "bitcoin"
tweets = client.search_recent_tweets(query=crypto_coin, max_results=10)
```

For more information:

https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api

https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/client.html#tweepy.Client.search_recent_tweets

I hope this helps.