# tweepy data error Forbidden: 403 Forbidden

Tags: json, python-3.x, data-science, tweepy

```
import tweepy, codecs

consumer_key = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

consumer_secret = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

access_token = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

access_token_secret = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

Bearer_token = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)

auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth)

api.update_status("Hello from Python for Udemy Data Science and Machine Learning Course")
```

ERROR

```
Forbidden                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[8], line 1
----> 1 api.update_status("Hello from Python for Udemy Data Science and Machine Learning Course")

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tweepy\api.py:46, in payload.<locals>.decorator.<locals>.wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
     44 kwargs['payload_list'] = payload_list
     45 kwargs['payload_type'] = payload_type
---> 46 return method(*args, **kwargs)

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tweepy\api.py:979, in API.update_status(self, status, **kwargs)
    976 if 'media_ids' in kwargs:
    977     kwargs['media_ids'] = list_to_csv(kwargs['media_ids'])
--> 979 return self.request(
    980     'POST', 'statuses/update', endpoint_parameters=(
    981         'status', 'in_reply_to_status_id',
    982         'auto_populate_reply_metadata', 'exclude_reply_user_ids',
    983         'attachment_url', 'media_ids', 'possibly_sensitive', 'lat',
    984         'long', 'place_id', 'display_coordinates', 'trim_user',
    985         'card_uri'
    986     ), status=status, **kwargs
    987 )

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tweepy\api.py:271, in API.request(self, method, endpoint, endpoint_parameters, params, headers, json_payload, parser, payload_list, payload_type, post_data, files, require_auth, return_cursors, upload_api, use_cache, **kwargs)
    269     raise Unauthorized(resp)
    270 if resp.status_code == 403:
--> 271     raise Forbidden(resp)
    272 if resp.status_code == 404:
    273     raise NotFound(resp)

Forbidden: 403 Forbidden
453 - You currently have access to a subset of Twitter API v2 endpoints and limited v1.1 endpoints (e.g. media post, oauth) only. If you need access to this endpoint, you may need a different access level. You can learn more here: https://developer.twitter.com/en/portal/product
```

How is solved this error? I researched the code and watched the video, but the error was not resolved.

Comment: Have you checked out what line 453 is telling you? Do you have the right access permissions? Also, you don't include the `Bearer_token` value anywhere

Comment: yes but It didn't happen

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I fix '403 Forbidden' error when using Tweepy to access the Twitter API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76810100/how-do-i-fix-403-forbidden-error-when-using-tweepy-to-access-the-twitter-api)

Answer (score 1):

Twitter has phased out API v1 so you need to use v2. So for tweepy you can use tweepy.Client(v2) instead of tweepy.API(v1)
So your code when converted to tweepy.Client version will look like this.

```
import tweepy

consumer_key = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
consumer_secret = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
access_token = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
access_token_secret = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
Bearer_token = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

client = tweepy.Client(Bearer_token, consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token, access_token_secret)

client.create_tweet(text="Hello from Python for Udemy Data Science and Machine Learning Course")
```

And this will work as you would expect it to work.