# Error code 453 when authenticating/posting to Twitter API 2.0 in Python using Tweepy

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I'm currently working on a Twitter bot using the Tweepy library to interact with the Twitter API. Recently, I encountered Error Code 453 with the message:

> "You currently have access to a subset of Twitter API v2 endpoints and limited v1.1 endpoints (e.g. media post, oauth) only. If you need access to this endpoint, you may need a different access level."

I've already tried regenerating my API keys and bearer tokens, and I'm confident that I haven't exceeded my rate limits. However, I'm still unable to access the required endpoints. Has anyone else encountered this issue, and does anyone have insights or suggestions on how to resolve it?

Here's the code:

```
import tweepy
from PIL import Image
import io
import requests
import os
import time
from datetime import datetime

# Twitter API authentication (as shown in previous answers)
consumer_key = 'XXXX'
consumer_secret = 'XXXX'
access_token = 'XXXX'
access_token_secret = 'XXXX'

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

# Function to check for new images in the designated folder
def check_for_new_images(image_folder, posted_images_file):
    posted_images = set()

    # Read the list of posted images from the text file
    if os.path.exists(posted_images_file):
        with open(posted_images_file, 'r') as file:
            posted_images = set(file.read().splitlines())

    new_images = []

    # Loop through files in the image folder
    for filename in os.listdir(image_folder):
        if filename.lower().endswith(('.jpg', '.jpeg', '.png')) and filename not in posted_images:
            new_images.append(filename)

    return new_images

# Function to post an image as a tweet
def post_image_tweet(api, image_folder, image_filename):
    image_path = os.path.join(image_folder, image_filename)
    tweet_text = image_filename.split('.')[0]  # Use the image filename as the tweet text
    
    try:
        media = api.media_upload(image_path)
        api.update_status(status=tweet_text, media_ids=[media.media_id])
        current_time = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        print(f"Image '{image_filename}' has been posted at {current_time}")
        
        return True
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error posting tweet: {e}")
        return False

# Print Twitter API rate limits
rate_limits = api.rate_limit_status()['resources']

# Main loop
image_folder = '/Users/jmy/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/COULUERS_TWITT_POST'  # Replace with the path to your designated folder
posted_images_file = 'posted_images.txt'

while True:
    new_images = check_for_new_images(image_folder, posted_images_file)
    
    if new_images:
        for image_filename in new_images:
            if post_image_tweet(api, image_folder, image_filename):
                # Mark the image as posted
                with open(posted_images_file, 'a') as file:
                    file.write(image_filename + '\n')
    
    # Print rate limits
    print("Rate Limits:", rate_limits)
    
    time.sleep(6 * 60 * 60)  # Sleep for 6 hours before checking again
```

I've already tried regenerating my API keys and bearer tokens, and I'm confident that I haven't exceeded my rate limits. However, I'm still unable to access the required endpoints. Has anyone else encountered this issue, and does anyone have insights or suggestions on how to resolve it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I fix '403 Forbidden' error when using Tweepy to access the Twitter API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76810100/how-do-i-fix-403-forbidden-error-when-using-tweepy-to-access-the-twitter-api)